# HTML Code to Display Month and Year on static website

Tags: html, static

I want to display month and year on my static HTML website .
I also want to update it automatically, means its running October like Oct 2018, in Next month, It will Nov 2018.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var date = new Date();

    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear();
};
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following codes in your site footer, make sure to add the javascript code inside the script tag.

```js
var date = new Date();

var months = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getFullYear();
```

```html
<p id="year"></p>
```